# Custom User Model, Custom Authentication not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am a beginner in Django and I am working on a project which requires Custom user model as I Don't require is_staff, is_superuser, is_admin.

So, but searching and other ways I made my own Custom user model. But it is not working and I am stuck on it for days.

It will be a huge help if someone can help me with the code.

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Usermanagement'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'accounts.backends.EmailAuthBackend',
]
```

backends.py

```
#backends.py

# from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

Usermanagement = get_user_model()

class EmailAuthBackend:
    def authenticate(self,request,username=None,password=None):
        print(request)
        try:
            user = Usermanagement.objects.get(emailid=username)
            print(password)
            print(user.password)
            # print(check_password(password))
            # print(user.check_password(password))
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
            return None
            
        except user.DoesNotExist:
            return None
    
    def get_user(self,user_id): 
        try:
            return user.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except user.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

views.py

```
# views.py

def loginPage(request):
    # POST
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request,data=request.POST)

# loginPage.html the html tag has attribute name = username for email , 
# name = password for password

        if form.is_valid(): # Form Valid
            email = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            #Check
            print("EMAIL: ",email)
            print("PASSWORD: ",password)
            # Authentication USER
            user = authenticate(request,username=email,password=password)
            print("Authenticated ",user) # Check
            # check
            print(user)

            if user is not None: # If User found
                login(request,user,backend='accounts.backends.EmailAuthBackend')
                messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {email}.")
                return redirect("home")

            else: # If User Not found
                messages.error(request,"User not found")
                return HttpResponse("User not found, not able to login")

        else: # Form InValid
            messages.error(request,"Invalid username or password.")
            return HttpResponse("Form Invalid")
    # GET
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
        context = {"form":form}
        return render(request,"loginPage.html",context=context)
```

urls.py and other configurations are correct.

Problems:

1. check_password : always False
2. In DB I have unencrypted password ( ex:- password=admin )
3. DB is a legacy(existing) DB , so I first made the DB and then I did "python manage.py inspectdb" , which created models for me and then I changed few things, but did not changed the field names or the db_table name.
4. I am very much ok to create user through SHELL.
5. In loginPage.html the html tag has attribute name = username for email , name = password for password

if any other requirements I will edit the Questions

Answer (score 0):

i think you cannot use the **check_password** function in your case, because it has been created for encrypted password case. Just make a `user.password == password` in your **EmailAuthBackend**

For second problem with get_user(), I think your userId is not the primary key for Django maybe, problem probably can be solved by filter directly by **userId**:

```
    def get_user(self, user_id): 
        try:
            return user.objects.get(userId=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Comment: thanks man, it's working , but in "EmailAuthBackend" the "get_user" method is not working....any clue how can i make it work

Comment: @Nipun ok i add something about this problem. To try, i am not sure

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the problem No.2

Remove the `password=password` in your `user=self.model()`

It's making it difficult to make reference to the password in your `user.set_password()`